# Sending emails in test mode with ActionMailer in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am having a slightly odd problem with sending mail in test mode with Rails 3

It seems that my mailers are not returning anything.  For example I have a mailer called UserMailer.  Users can make changes that require approval in the app so this has a method called changes_approved that should send the user an email notifying them that their changes have been approved.class

```
UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "from@example.com"

  def changes_approved(user, page)

    @user = user
    @page = page

    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Your changes have been approved")

  end

end
```

In my controller I have the following line

```
UserMailer.changes_approved(@page_revision.created_by, @page_revision.page).deliver
```

However my tests fail at this point with the error:

undefined method `deliver' for nil:NilClass

When I trigger the same actions on the development site tho (http://localhost:3000 through a browser), the emails are sent out correctly and everything works quite happily

And to add further confusion, I am using devise for authentication and the emails for that seem to be working correctly both in test and development modes.  Certainly I am not getting this same error and according to my email-spec tests, everythings working

So this leads me to believe that I have a problem with my mailers rather than my test mail config per se but I have no idea what.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have found the answer,

it looks like the problem was in the way I was testing these mailers.  In each of the controller tests I had a line similar to

```
UserMailer.should_receive(:changes_approved).with(user, page)
```

Whilst this test was passing fine, it appeared to break the mailer itself.  I have removed this line from the tests and now they pass ok.  Subsequent tests against ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last to check the details of the sent email are correct appear to be ok so I am happy that this line is not neccessary.

If anyone has an explanation as to why this breaks tho, I would be interested to find out

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 10):

I used https://gist.github.com/1031144
to convert

```
# Rails 2 method:
UserMailer.should_receive(:deliver_signup)
```

to

```
# Cumbersome Rails 3 method:
mailer = mock
mailer.should_receive(:deliver)
UserMailer.should_receive(:signup).and_return(mailer)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem - probably the UserMailer.changes_approved method is being replaced with a mock method, which returns nil (I wasn't using shoulda for that test, but that's my best guess).

My code looked like this (modified to use your example):

```
UserMailer.expects(:changes_approved).once
```

I fixed it with an additional stub:

```
@mailer = stub(:deliver)
UserMailer.expects(:changes_approved).once.returns(@mailer)
```

The nil is now replaced with @mailer.

Answer (score 2):

To test the delayed action  mailer we need to first change the configuration of delayed_job (in config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb) to

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
```

and in your tests the expectation should be set to

```
mock_mail = mock(:mail)
mock_mail.should_receive(:deliver)
UserMailer.should_receive(:changes_approved).with(user, page).and_return(mock_mail)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. This is exactly how you get your [RSpec](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec) + [email_spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) + [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) specs passing. Use [Workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) to dynamically spin up workers as needed locally and on Heroku.